# C: segfault in doubly linked list when deleting first element

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

My code is giving a segfault when trying to deleteFirst() on the last element in the link. It will delete everything fine, but when there's one element left in the list and I try to delete it, it gives me a segfault error.

Any ideas? I think there's something wrong with the deleteFirst() function.

Typedef and structs:

```
typedef struct NodeStruct {
    long data;
    struct NodeStruct* next;
    struct NodeStruct* prev;
} NodeStruct;

//  Rename NodeStruct* as NodePtr
typedef NodeStruct* NodePtr;

typedef struct ListStruct {
    NodePtr first;
    NodePtr last;
    NodePtr current;
} ListStruct;

//  ListHndl is just a ListStruct* renamed.
```

Insert function:

```
void insertOrder(ListHndl L, long data) {

    NodePtr tmp = newNode();
    tmp->data = data;

    NodePtr prev = NULL;
    NodePtr curr = L->first;

    while (curr != NULL && data > curr->data) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL) L->last = tmp;
    if (prev == NULL) L->first = tmp;
    else prev->next = tmp;
    tmp->next = curr;
    }
```

delete function:

```
void deleteFirst(ListHndl L) {
    assert (!isEmpty(L));
    NodePtr tmp = L->first;
    L->first = L->first->next;
    L->first->prev = NULL;
    free(tmp);
    }
```

Code in main:

```
insertOrder(List1, 50);
insertOrder(List1, 20);
insertOrder(List1, 1);
deleteFirst(List1);
deleteFirst(List1);
deleteFirst(List1); // <--------   Deleting last element gives segfault.
printList(NULL, List1); //Print to STDOUT
```

Comment: Assume every pointer can be NULL and test before using. There must be many copies of this question floating around...

Answer (score 3):

Because when you only have one element in the list, L->first->next is NULL.

Comment: the same bug still exists.

Answer (score 1):

On your deleteFirst() function switch this line `L->first->prev = NULL;` with:

```
if(L->first) 
    L->first->prev = NULL;
```

Because, for the last element in your list, your L->first is the next of your old first, which is NULL!

So `L->first->prev` will lead to segfault!

Comment: Wow, that was way easier than I thought. Thank you so much.